# Dealing with Union-Find algorithms with a lot of objects

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, iteration, union-find

I have a problem with (not anymore with stackoverflow (hehe)) Find algorithm when trying to implement UnionFind structure algorithm with path-compression.

I have standard array of ints, array can get pretty big -> it works fine until 60.000.000 elements.

My Union function looks like this:

```
public void unite(int p, int q) {
    if(p >= 0 && p < id.length && q >= 0 && q < id.length){
        if (isInSameSet(p, q)) return;
        id[find(p)] = find(q); 
        stevilo--;
    }
}
```

My isInSameSet looks like this:

```
    public boolean isInSameSet(int p, int q) {
        if(p >= 0 && p < id.length && q >= 0 && q < id.length) 
            return find(p) == find(q);
        return false;
}
```

I have tried iterative way in Find:

```
    public int find(int i) {
        while (i != id[i]){
            id[i] = id[id[i]];
            i = id[i];              
        }       
    return i;
    }
```

and tail-recrusion:

```
    public int find(int i) {    
        int p = id[i];
        if (i == p) {
          return i;
        }
        return id[i] = find(p);     
     }
```

Is there anything I missed in my code? Is there any other approach to this kind of problems?

@edit: Adding constructor to code:

```
    public UnionFind(int N) {
        stevilo = N;
        id = new int[N];        
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            id[i] = i;
        }
```

@edit2 (better explanation and new findings):
The problem is not in stackoverflow anymore for less then 60.000.000 elements, which is more then enough for solving my problems.

I'm calling test Unions like this:

```
for(i=0;i<id.length-1;i++)
unite(i,i+1)
```

so the ending pairs are like this:

```
0:1, 1:2, 2:3, 3:4,..
```

which is only example of least optimal option for testing means only :)

Then I check if representative of 0 is last element in table (99 for 100 elements) and it works.

Problem is, that my algorithm works only if initial elements are each in their own union (0:0, 1:1, 2:2, 3:3). If I have different Unions already set up (0:2, 1:6, 2:1, 3:5, ...) my testing algorithm stops working.

I have narrow it down to a problem in Find function, probably something to do with path compression

```
id[i] = id[id[i]].
```

Comment: It would be better to post a complete compilable example along with the error stacktrace. I suspect an infinite loop/recursion in your code.

Comment: Your iterative `find` is not correct. It doesn't do path compression. If you had `1->2->3->4->5` you end up with `1->3,2->4,3->5`

Comment: Altough its over year and a half old question, you are correct, its it wrong, thats why I asked peeps here for help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once wrote an algorithm for `UnionFind`, and its time complexity is O(log*(n)). Thats iterative logarithm of n. The algorithm compresses the path of the tree as it keeps on connecting the nodes to gain efficiency. I find it very efficient, though I haven't practically tested it against huge array size. Here's the code:

```
public class UnionFind
{
  private int[] id;

  public UnionFind(int capacity)
  {
    id = new int[capacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
    {
      id[i] = i;
    }
  }

  public boolean isConnected(int p, int q)
  {
    return root(p) == root(q);
  }

  public void connect(int p, int q)
  {
    if (isConnected(p, q))
    {
      return;
    }

    id[root(p)] = root(q);
  }

  private int root(int p)
  {
    int temp = p;

    if (p != id[p] && id[id[p]] != id[p])
    {
      while (p != id[p])
      {
        p = id[p];
      }

      id[temp] = id[p];
    }

    return id[p];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One small optimization would be to get rid of isInSameSet...

```
public void unite(int p, int q) {
    if(p >= 0 && p < id.length && q >= 0 && q < id.length){
        int rootp = find(p);
        int rootq = find(q);
        if (rootp==rootq) return;
        id[rootp] = rootq; 
        stevilo--;
    }
}
```

Comment: True, I gained 0.2seconds before getting stackoverflow with 100000000 elements. But need to look further..

Comment: If you post more of your code, you will get more help on optimizing it :)

Comment: Added constructor (which makes this complete code that I have..) to first post, not sure if it will help. I'm testing this thing on making Unions in sequence, making one long tree, then trying to find last item in this "list"..

Comment: Actually no, I'm calling it like this: for(i=0;i<id.length-1;i++)unite(i,i+1), so the ending pairs are like this: 0:1, 1:2, 2:3, 3:4, ...

Comment: but then you end up with all nodes sitting in the same cluster?

Answer (score 2):

Union-Find data structures typically include TWO different optimizations.  One is path compression.  You have that.

But the other optimization happens during a Union, where you carefully choose which of the two roots to make a child of the other, usually via Union-By-Rank or Union-By-Size.  With that optimization, your trees should never be deep enough to get a stack overflow.  However, that optimization seems to be missing from your unite function.

Comment: Adding weighting usually requires another array. With numbers this big, that array halves the amount of heap that I have available..

Comment: Sure, although with Union-by-Rank, the ranks will never get very big.  A byte is plenty big enough.  An extra array of bytes would only increase your memory footprint by 25%, not double it.